# How do I implement range function for values that are in string dtype using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

My MongoDB database has multiple documents like these:

```
{"t": "p",
 "p1": {
     "Temperature": "28.30",
     "Humidity": "57.20"
 }
}
```

how do I get temperature values in the range of (10.00, 16.00) and humidity values in the range of (20.00, 69.99) using pymongo

```
humidity_range_counter = 0
for i in collection.find({"pl.Humidity": "55.00"}):
   humidity_counter += 1
print(humidity_range_counter)
```

The above code gives proper count for this value. Now how do I insert range?

Answer (score 0):

Query

- i think you should change your schema to store the numbers as doubles not as strings
- this converts them first to double, and checks each value to be in the range here `10-16` and `20-69.90`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=630a1d6f78a49d8782851489)

```js
yourColl.aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$and": 
       [{"$gte": [{"$toDouble": "$p1.Temperature"}, 10]},
         {"$lte": [{"$toDouble": "$p1.Temperature"}, 16]},
         {"$gte": [{"$toDouble": "$p1.Humidity"}, 20]},
         {"$lte": [{"$toDouble": "$p1.Humidity"}, 69.90]}]}}}])
```